# WCF REST JSON request: Formatter exception

Tags: json, rest

I have a enum as one of the parameters in my Rest API.

**End Point contract:**

```
List<Transaction> GetTransactions(int employeeID, int recordOffset, int recordLimit, TransactionType transactionType = TransactionType.All);
```

**InputJSON Request:**

```
{
            "employeeID":"123",
            "recordOffset": 0,
            "recordLimit": 80,
            "transactionType":"All"
}
```

I'm getting a 400 bad request, when i pass this input JSON with transactionType key.

Please let me know how, i should be passing an ENUM value in the json request.

```
public enum TransactionType
{
    All = 0,
    Incoming = 1,
    Outgoing = 2
}
```

Exception Message:

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://Services/2015/03:transactionType. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type Entities.TransactionType. The value 'All' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int64'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter expected is an `int`. 
You should be passing an int value of `0`, `1` or `2` in the JSON request here.

Depending on how you build up your JSON request, you could add the value of the Enum you want, e.g `transactionType = TransactionType.All`

This way, you can actually use your Enum when building up your request to ensure you use viable values.

Comment: My pleasure. Also check, the `employeeID` is a `string`, where `GetTransactions()` expects an `int` for `employeeID`